# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined using React and babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, module, babeljs

When running my app on my localhost, everything works fine, but when I deploy to Heroku, on an onClick event, I get a Chrome DevTools error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`.

It appears that this line in my compiled js file is creating this error:

```
function(e) {
        void 0 === module || void 0 === module.exports ? t.jsfeat = e : module.exports = e
    }
```

I certainly want to fix it, but I don't understand why it works when I run my app on localhost but does not work once deployed.

I am using Node, Express, React, and PostgreSQL, compiling with babel. In searching the issue, it seems like it may be a webpack/babel setup issue, and for some reason it is not compiling correctly?

My deployed app (that doesn't work when clicking 'start'!): https://dev-eq.herokuapp.com/learn 
My code: https://github.com/wallacepreston/eq-dev